# How to sort String array Alphabetically in android?

Tags: android, arrays, sorting

I know there are many solutions to this question, but I am still facing a error. I have a string array, and the data to the array is inserted through webservice .
Below is my code.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            int dip = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                    (float) 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            JSONArray jarray;

            try {
                jarray= new JSONArray(result);
                    name= new String[jarray.length()];
for (int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){

                    JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                name[i]=    jobj.getString("Name");
}
```

Now in name[i] I get the names ,but those are not arranged alphabetically. I tried Arrays.sort(name); but it is giving me null pointer.[image]

Comment: Post logcat of Null Pointer

Comment: Use arrayList, you can sort easily

Comment: if answer is feasible than please accept it that it will help others while they will have same type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

For alphabetic comparation you can use method  [`compareTo(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29). 
sorting mechnism you will have to develop yourself or use ArrayList an [`Collections.sort()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E%29) method.